# Проблема после добавления Admob на проект

Tags: java, android, admob

Кто-нибудь может подсказать чем грозит моему проекту удаление с dependencies на грейдле следующей строчки.
com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1

И может ли его заменить следующая строчка?
com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1

Если я удаляю обе эти строчки, то кнопочки на проекте исчезают. А если оставляю обе то выходит своеобразная ошибка

А если оставляю только com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1, то все норм стартует.

Спасибо!

Comment: Что за кнопочки исчезают? 0_о

Comment: Обычная buttonview. Вернее его background-скин который я взял с гугловских заготовок.

Comment: Сама кнопка есть. А background-а с Nine,png формата нету.

Comment: Мне бы получить подтверждение того, что второй наследует все признаки первого.